# Guidance on how to best register the EventGridClient with DI in a .NET 5.0 Worker Service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-5, azure-eventgrid

I'm using the EventGridClient from the Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid NuGet package to publish events to an Azure Event Grid Topic. I understand that worker services are registered with singleton lifetime. I'm looking for guidance on how to best register the EventGridClient with the DI container in a worker service? I'm using a .NET 5.0 worker hosted in a windows services.

DI registration (not sure if I've done the right thing here):

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseWindowsService()
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddSingleton(new EventGridClient(new TopicCredentials("topicKey"), // proxy auth
        new HttpClientHandler {DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials}));
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

})
.Build()
.Run();
```

Worker implementation:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly EventGridClient client;
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> logger;

    public Worker(EventGridClient client, ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var events = new List<EventGridEvent>();

            await client.PublishEventsAsync("topicHostname", events, stoppingToken);

            logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer from Microsoft on their Q & A site which i'm pasting here in case someone else faces the same question.

> While your DI registration is technically fine and yes, it should be singleton as it involves http connection ([refer Improper Instantiation antipattern for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/)), you can make it nicer and testable by registering the interface `IEventGridClient` against `EventGridClient` and inject IEventGridClient instead.

```
//...
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
 {
     services.AddSingleton<IEventGridClient>(new EventGridClient(new TopicCredentials("topicKey"), // proxy auth
         new HttpClientHandler {DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials}));
     services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    
 })
```

...

```
private readonly IEventGridClient client;
     private readonly ILogger<Worker> logger;
    
     public Worker(IEventGridClient client, ILogger<Worker> logger)
     {
         this.client = client;
         this.logger = logger;
     }
```

> But note that since PublishEventsAsync is an extension method of
> IEventGridClient, if you write unit test for your code and inject a
> mock of IEventGridClient, remember to mock setup the method
> `PublishEventsWithHttpMessages` of IEventGridClient so that your test
> does not make a real call to event grid.